# Как закрыть все сессии?

Tags: php, сессия

сайт на пхп, каждая страница выполняет несколько пхп кодов (вывод данных из БД, вывод последней статьи из БД, вывод количества просмотров из БД и тд).
посетителей у сайта 600 уников в день. которые просматривают всего 1200 страниц. 
страниц на сайте 1500 примерно. но нагрузка на сервер большая.

КАК закрывать все сессий в конце документа пхп ? 
п.с. пробовал mysql_close() не помогает, пишет ошибку.

Comment: открытые сессии не влияют на нагрузку.

Comment: хорошо, задам вопрос по другому - можно ли вообще просто закрыть все сессии кодом в конце файла?

Comment: @meravaz, нормальное завершение скрипта гарантирует автоматическое закрытие открытых подключений (сессии - это совсем другое) к БД. При желании можно хранить список подключений (скорее всего, там только одно) и закрывать их вручную с помощью mysql_close.  
Я повторю еще раз: само по себе открытое подключение к БД несет практически нулевую нагрузку и несравнимо с даже самым простым запросом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пока Вы не будете сами осознавать, где может утечь память или как оптимизировать использование ресурсов, положитесь на garbage collector. 
Если же всё таки очень нужно, то такой волшебной кнопочки - оптимизировать всё не существует. Простите.

Comment: З.Ы. Доставте памяти, инода помогает ;)

Comment: запрос - вывод статьи - сессия открылась, выдал статью - сессия не закрылась сервер предполагает что еще что то будет. как закрыть сессию. вот вопрос.

Comment: Что Вы вкладываете в понятие "сессия"?

Comment: @meravaz вы оперируете какими-то понятиями, которые не находят отклика в моем профессиональном глоссарии. Распишите, пожалуйста, подробно, что происходит и как вы определили те или иные проблемы.

Comment: постараюсь все заново и подробно рассказать
сайт - пхп. статьи есессно с БД СКЛ. 
статьи выводятся по принципу index.php?id=1 
так же есть справа информеры с той же самой БД, где выводятся данные уже с другой таблицы предположим с статистикой наиболее просматриваемых статей.
авторизации пользователей нет и не было. 
пользователи просто приходят читают статьи и уходят. 
в день 600 уников, просматривают примерно по 2-3 страницы каждый.

Comment: вопрос: сервер сообщает о высокой нагрузке. предположительно из за то го что сессии не закрываются. то есть запрос сделан на вывод статьи - выполнен запрос - но сервер продолжает думать что будут еще запросы так как сессия не закрыта.

Comment: @meravaz какая такая сессия ? keep alive ? На что нагрузка ? на память или проц ?

Comment: @eicto, он про подключения к БД  
@meravaz, поверьте, пустое подключение не отжирает практически ничего. Там висит просто ожидание сообщения от скрипта, и в это время не происходит никакой работы, максимум - пустой цикл.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, функция `mysql_connect` устарела, и [не рекомендуется к использованию](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php). Начните с перехода на [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Код из [документации](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php):

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Ваш код

mysqli_close($link);
```

В данном примере вы подключаетесь к сокету UNIX используя [ключевое слово `localhost`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php). Если же вы хотите, как обычно, соединиться по TCP, то замените первую строчку данного кода на:

```
$link = mysqli("127.0.0.1", $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
```

Кроме того, согласно [документации mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php):

> Новое подключение создается, только
> если в пуле не найдется свободного
> подключения с теми же данными хоста,
> имени пользователя, пароля, сокета,
> порта и базы данных по умолчанию.
> Механизм постоянных соединений можно
> включать и выключать PHP директивой
> [`mysqli.allow_persistent`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.allow-persistent).

Answer (score 0):

Я, кажется, понял, что вы хотите. И, насколько я знаю, вам ничего делать не надо. Соединение mysql_connect происходит каждый раз при загрузке пользователем страницы и каждый раз само закрывается (ведь это бы назвали сессией?). Кроме того, вполне приличный ресурс - php.su. Все функции расписаны по категориям. Кто ищет, тот всегда найдет!
**UPDATE** Специально для комментирующих и минусующих. Я не посылал человека искать ответ, я сам ответил, почитайте еще раз: соединение каждый раз закрывается само. Так что мне непонятно ваше недовольство. Если я не прав про соединение, то так и скажите.
P.S. Прошу прошение за то, что не могу отвечать в комментарии.

Comment: > php.su

     

>  Новости портала
> 04.03.2010: Релиз ветки 5.3 (PHP 5.3.2)

о даааа  
функции там вроде тупо склонированы с основной документации

Comment: Меня очень умиляет склонность некоторых людей посылать человека самостоятельно искать ответ в документации. Он, несомненно, публиковал вопрос на ХешКоде как раз для того, чтобы получить этот бесценный совет.

Comment: @Risto, это нормально, главное ссылку в нужный кусок доки дать. А если не может прочитать - пусть наймет того кто может. Доки написаны людьми для людей, лучше чем в доках - только в исходниках. У PHP отличная документация, очень мало пробелов и косяков, почти вся переведена. Вопросы имеет смысл задавать только если прочитал уже доку.

Comment: @eicto, так в том-то и дело, что топикстартера просто послали самостоятельно искать ответ в доках, без ссылок на конкретные функции. Причём на сайте, где информация заведомо вторична.

Comment: @Risto, ну, автор имел в виду скрипты-туториалы оттуда, я уверен. Другое дело, что они написаны процедурно донельзя.

Comment: @Risto, про php.su согласен - он вообще почти не нужен, это всё местячковость, вместо того чтобы помочь сообществу - пилят свой ресурс, в то время как переводить и комментировать php.net можно абсолютно всем.

Comment: @eicto, одно время на php.net дичайше глючил вывод статей на не-английском: Регулярно забывался выбранный пользователем язык, а локализованные страницы открывались через раз. Тогда в php.su таки был смысл. Но не сейчас.

Comment: @psix-dev, как показывает практика, коннекты закрываются [не всегда][1]. В чём дело в данном конкретном случае я знать не могу, ибо не видел ни кода, ни текста ошибки, возвращаемой `mysql_close()`, но вмжу, что топикстартер использует устаревшую функцию, которую в любом случае надо заменить, на что ему и указал.


  [1]: http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/8803/linux-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B4